# Horizontal line between two words

Tags: html, css, css-position, line

How can I add a line between this two words with css:

Last Action Items------------------------------View more----

Without the "-"

I did this: https://jsfiddle.net/3L766kdo/1/ but I think there is a better way to do it (with the line surrounding View More)

HTML

```
<div class='container c-decorated-header'>
  <h3><span>Last Action items</span></h3>
  <div class='c-decorated-header_link-view-more'>
    <a href="www.something.com">View More</a>
  </div>
<div>
```

SCSS

```
.c-decorated-header {
  position: relative;
  h3 {
    position: relative;
    color: #7B8291;
    width: 79%;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e6;
    line-height: 0.1em;
    margin: 35px 0 0px;
  }
  h3 span {
    position: relative;
    font-size: .6em;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-stretch: condensed;
    background: #f5f4f4;
  }
  &_link-view-more {
    position: absolute;
    width: 96%;
    text-align: right;
    top: -5px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(87, 135, 253);
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't just add a line between two words with CSS. CSS serves the purpose of styling your pages not dynamically add something between some elements. You have javascript for that. And if you want to add a horizontal line by default, you can use:
 LastActionItems<hr></hr>View more in your html code.

Comment: Yes, when building the HTML, just add <hr></hr> between your words... or if that for some reason doesn't suit your needs, you can literally just add however many '---'s you want between the words as you build the HTML.

Comment: What does your html structure look like?

Comment: Maybe `css` `text-decoration`  `strikethrough` with non-breaking spaces?

Comment: I updated my question :)

Comment: Something like this --> https://jsfiddle.net/3L766kdo/2/ ?

Comment: Yesss!!! exactly @UncaughtTypeError thanks! I would mark your answer as the correct one but this is a comment :P, if you put the answer I will mark it

Comment: Oh nice, glad it's what you're after - answer posted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution demonstrated in the Code Snippet embedded below utilizes existing elements with no further additions or adjustments to the DOM, or html structure.

An *absolutely* positioned *pseudo-element* is used to function as the required horizontal line resulting in the intended behaviour.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.c-decorated-header {
  position: relative;
}

.c-decorated-header h3 {
  position: relative;
  color: #7B8291;
  text-align: left;
}

.c-decorated-header h3:after {
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 100px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #e2e2e6;
}

.c-decorated-header h3 span {
  position: relative;
  font-size: .6em;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-stretch: condensed;
  background: #f5f4f4;
}

.c-decorated-header_link-view-more {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #5787fd;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container c-decorated-header'>
  <h3><span>Last Action items</span></h3>
  <div class='c-decorated-header_link-view-more'>
    <a href="www.something.com">View More</a>
  </div>
<div>
```

[JSFiddle Demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/3L766kdo/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using text-decoration:

```html
Last Action Items<span style="text-decoration: line-through">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>View more<span style="text-decoration: line-through">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
```

Or use an `inline-block`

```html
Last Action Items<span style="display:inline-block; width:100px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; line-height:0">&nbsp;</span>View more
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat cleaner version of @RobAu his second solution.
It should work.

```css
span {
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  line-height:0
}
```

```html
Last Action Items<span style="width: 100px">&nbsp;</span>View more<span style="width: 50px">&nbsp;</span>
```